# remove extra space from cardview

Tags: android, cardview

I have created a cardview below

[image]

my code is :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i want to remove space extra space from left,right,top and bottom like below image :-

[image]

how can i do dis?

Comment: `android:layout_margin="5dp"` in `CardView` might be the issue

Comment: i remove it also but nothing has changed

Comment: @ManishaKhatke clean-rebuild and run

Comment: Make sure RecyclerView is not having any margin or padding

Comment: @ManishaKhatke remove `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` .ImageView Section .

Answer (score 1):

**android:layout_margin**

> Specifies extra space on the 4 side of view .

**Remove** below Property from your **XML**

```
android:layout_margin="5dp".
```

**EDIT**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" //REMOVE this 
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:layout_margin="5dp`" from `Cardview`.

Comment: i have remove it but nothing has changed

Comment: Please post screenshot after remove margin.

Comment: Please make sure main layout in which you have define recycler view doesn't have margin or padding. If have then please remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it in a recycler view or list view?

Comment: it is in recycler view

Comment: post your recycler view code.. may be you have given margin in that layout

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />